# How can I manipulate multiple functions which all have the same parameters?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, manipulate

So I've been plotting phase portraits along with nullclines and phase flow for certain oscillators as follows:

```
tmax = 200; solution = NDSolve[{
   f''[t] + f[t] + f'[t]^{3} - 3 f'[t] == 0,
   f[0] == 3,
   f'[0] == 3
   },
  f, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> 100000, AccuracyGoal -> 12, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 12]

splot = StreamPlot[{y - x^3 + 3 x, -x}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   StreamColorFunction -> {None}, StreamStyle -> {Gray}, Axes -> True,
    Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["q", Bold, 12], Style["p", Bold, 12]}
   , RotateLabel -> False,
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red, Orange}, {"q(t), p(t)", "q'", 
       "p'"}] , Right], LabelStyle -> {14, GrayLevel[0.3]}];
plot1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{-f'[t], f[t]} /. solution], {t, 180, 200}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> All];
nplot1 = Plot[{y = x^{3} - 3 x}, {x, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Red}];
nplot2 = 
  ContourPlot[x == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Orange, Dashed}];
Show[splot, plot1, nplot1, nplot2]
```

which gives:
[image]
I'd like to create a similar plot which allows me to manipulate the parameters omeganaught, mu, and qnaught. I've tried the following code to no avail, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   p''[t] + omeganaught^{2}*p[t] + 
     mu*((1/(3*omeganaught))*p'[t]^{3} - qnaught^{2}*p'[t]) == 0,
   p[0] == 3,
   p'[0] == 3
   },
  {p}, {t, 0, 200}, {omeganaught, mu, qnaught}, MaxSteps -> 1000000, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 12]

plot2 = Manipulate[
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[
     {-p'[t], p[t]} & /@ sol[omeganaught, mu, qnaught]], {t, 0, 200},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue},
    PlotRange -> All],
   {{omeganaught, 0.1}, 0, 10}, {{mu, 0.1}, 0, 10}, {{qnaught, 0.1}, 
    0, 10}];

splot1 = StreamPlot[
   {omeganaught*y - mu*(((x^{3})/3) - qnaught^{2}*x), -omeganaught*
     x},
   {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
   StreamColorFunction -> {None}, StreamStyle -> {Gray}, Axes -> True,
    Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["q", Bold, 12], Style["p", Bold, 12]}
   , RotateLabel -> False,
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red, Orange}, {"q(t), p(t)", "q'", 
       "p'"}] , Right], LabelStyle -> {14, GrayLevel[0.3]}];

nplot3 = Plot[
   {y = (mu/omeganaught)*(((x^{3})/3) - qnaught^{2}*x)}, {x, -4, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red}];

nplot4 = 
  ContourPlot[x == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Orange, Dashed}];

Show[splot1, plot2, nplot3, nplot4]
```

I end up with an error "could not combine the graphics objects in show".
Even when I try just the ParametricPlot I end up with a blank plot.

I apologize for the long question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using `ParametricNDSolve` and solve `{p, p'}` simultaneously.
- We need to replace `x^{3}` and `qnaught^{2}` by `x^3` and `qnaught^2`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{p''[t] + omeganaught^{2}*p[t] + 
      mu*((1/(3*omeganaught))*p'[t]^{3} - qnaught^{2}*p'[t]) == 0, 
    p[0] == 3, p'[0] == 3}, {p, p'}, {t, 0, 200}, {omeganaught, mu, 
    qnaught}, MaxSteps -> 1000000, AccuracyGoal -> 12, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 12];
Manipulate[
 {ParametricPlot[{-p'[omeganaught, mu, qnaught]@t, 
      p[omeganaught, mu, qnaught]@t} /. sol, {t, 0, 200}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", AspectRatio -> 1],
   StreamPlot[{omeganaught*y - 
      mu*(((x^3)/3) + qnaught^2*x), -omeganaught*x}, {x, -4, 
     4}, {y, -4, 4}, StreamColorFunction -> {None}, 
    StreamStyle -> {Gray}, Axes -> True, 
    Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
    FrameLabel -> {Style["q", Bold, 12], Style["p", Bold, 12]}, 
    RotateLabel -> False, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red, Orange}, {"q(t), p(t)", "q'", 
        "p'"}], Right], LabelStyle -> {14, GrayLevel[0.3]}],
   Plot[{y = (mu/omeganaught)*(((x^3)/3) - qnaught^2*x)}, {x, -4, 4}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red}],
   ContourPlot[x == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
    ContourStyle -> {Orange, Dashed}]} // Show, {{omeganaught, 0.3}, 
  0, 10}, {{mu, 0.1}, 0, 10}, {{qnaught, 0.1}, 0, 10}]
```

[image]